# How to list swarm mode nodes?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

There is no list option

```
docker swarm list

Usage:  docker swarm COMMAND

Manage Swarm

Commands:
  ca          Display and rotate the root CA
  init        Initialize a swarm
  join        Join a swarm as a node and/or manager
  join-token  Manage join tokens
  leave       Leave the swarm
  unlock      Unlock swarm
  unlock-key  Manage the unlock key
  update      Update the swarm
```

How to get more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out.

```
docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
iiq90umkuazv565mzw0imyycg *   miki                Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.6
```

Comment: You need to be on the manager node for that command to work.